# Issue with xpaths to query data in a Hive table

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive

I am trying to get the correct xpath to query xml data contained as a string in a column called Message within a Hive table.
The xml comes from logs files from an internal system and I need to extract specific data from the the data.

To simplify the process, I attempted to extract the first set of data to ensure I had the correct xml xpath but after I create the view and perfrom a query, I get null values.

Below is a sample of the data and the Hive query I am running to create the view to just extract the 'SessionKey' to start with.

```
<AddOnlineToTrolley xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<accountSession
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <b:SessionKey>d472046f-fa15-4cf5-bbf0-ee35bdde28f4</b:SessionKey>
    <b:SessionToken i:nil="true"/>
</accountSession>
<OnlineProducts
    xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <b:OnlineProducts i:type="b:OnlineProductsCat">
        <b:AddToFavourites>true</b:AddToFavourites>
        <b:WeekDay>5</b:WeekDay>
        <b:ItemCount>1</b:ItemCount>
        <b:OrderOffset>0</b:OrderOffset>
        <b:FavouriteName>WeeklyPurchase</b:FavouriteName>
        <b:FirstOrderNumber>12505</b:FirstOrderNumber>
        <b:ProductId>312</b:ProductId>
        <b:Method>1</b:Method>
    </b:OnlineProducts>
</OnlineProducts>
</AddOnlineToTrolley>
```

**Hive Query**

```
DROP VIEW AddOnlineToTrolley;
CREATE VIEW AddOnlineToTrolley(SessionKey) 
   AS SELECT 
       xpath_string (message, '/AddOnlineToTrolley/accountSession[1]/*[namespace-             uri()=\'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ApplicationServices.DataContracts.Common\' and local-name()=\'SessionKey\'][1]'/'SessionKey')
 FROM onlineproductimport;

 Select * from AddOnlineToTrolley;
```

also tried some xpath statements quering the table directly and I still get nulls

```
 xpath(message, '/*[local-name()=\'AddOnlineToTrolley\']')
```

The ultimate goal is to create a view that people can use to query and pick and choice the data in the xml above but my strength is not Xpaths or XML

**View to contain the following:**

- SessionKey
- OnlineProducts
- AddToFavourites
- WeekDay
- ItemCount
- OrderOffset
- FavouriteName
- FirstOrderNumber
- ProductId
- Method

Comment: In my experience, unless the xml files has start and end tag in one single line,the xpath udf wont work. Can you try an example? Create a file and put only all tags between <accountSession> in one single line  and try using xpath. It should be something like this

Comment: Hi rVr, the xml does contain an end tags, I forgot to paste when I was creating the post. I have added the following above `</AddOnlineToTrolley>`.